# Einstein Bot not able to transfer chat to No Agent flow

Tags: liveagent, servicecloud, einstein, bots

As per the new release of Salesforce Winter ’20 for einstein bot in the service cloud

Reference: [link](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_einstein_bots.htm)

We have the new feature enabled which is based on the agent's availability i.e. when the user is offline it should redirect to "No agent" and that's how exactly it's working and after checking agents offline status bot ends the chat.

But I want to display some messages and create a case when there is No Agent (Offline) and other flow is followed when the agent is Online I am not sure how I can redirect my customer to Offline flow..??

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks